# Error installing VSFTPd 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, make

I'm following the [official documentation](http://vsftpd.devnet.ru/vsftpd/original/INSTALL) to install the 3.0.2 version of VSFTPd.

**Commands.**

```
$ wget https://security.appspot.com/downloads/vsftpd-3.0.2.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz vsftpd-3.0.2.tar.gz
$ cd vsftpd-3.0.2/
$ make
$ mkdir /usr/share/empty/
$ mkdir /var/ftp/
$ useradd -d /var/ftp ftp
$ chown root.root /var/ftp
$ chmod og-w /var/ftp
$ cp vsftpd /usr/local/sbin/vsftpd
$ cp vsftpd.conf.5 /usr/local/man/man5
$ cp vsftpd.8 /usr/local/man/man8
$ make install
```

And I get this error after `make install`:

```
if [ -x /usr/local/sbin ]; then \
    install -m 755 vsftpd /usr/local/sbin/vsftpd; \
else \
    install -m 755 vsftpd /usr/sbin/vsftpd; fi
if [ -x /usr/local/man ]; then \
        install -m 644 vsftpd.8 /usr/local/man/man8/vsftpd.8; \
        install -m 644 vsftpd.conf.5 /usr/local/man/man5/vsftpd.conf.5; \
elif [ -x /usr/share/man ]; then \
        install -m 644 vsftpd.8 /usr/share/man/man8/vsftpd.8; \
        install -m 644 vsftpd.conf.5 /usr/share/man/man5/vsftpd.conf.5; \
else \
        install -m 644 vsftpd.8 /usr/man/man8/vsftpd.8; \
        install -m 644 vsftpd.conf.5 /usr/man/man5/vsftpd.conf.5; fi
install: accessing `/usr/local/man/man8/vsftpd.8': Not a directory
install: accessing `/usr/local/man/man5/vsftpd.conf.5': Not a directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: Read the error message and make the needed directories.

Comment: I do that, but doesn't install again!

`mkdir -p /usr/local/man/man8 /usr/local/man/man5`

Comment: Why don't you use `aptitude`? Installation from tarball lowers maintainability and stability of your system.

Comment: While I am a big fan of using distro tools to install software, needing a newer version then the one shiped with your distro is one of the few exceptions I would make. Ubuntu ships 2.x, the poster wants 3.0.2

Comment: I just tried this on a ubuntu 12.04 system. I got the same error, but creating the missing directories fixed it. Maybe you forgot to use 'sudo' ? like 'sudo make install' ?

Comment: @Isaac : You are right re: lagging version in the distro.

Comment: I reinstall the Ubuntu and now probably works.
`whereis vsftpd` returns `vsftpd: /usr/local/sbin/vsftpd`. But I do `make install-vsftpd` to install the bootscript and returns this error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'install-vsftpd'.  Stop.`. Anyone know this error?

Comment: It tells you that the makefile does not define a "target" named "install-vsftpd". So there is not much you can do about it :) Where did you get the idea, that this target installs the bootscript? Maybe that ressource assumes a different makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create directories man5 and man8 by `mkdir -p /usr/local/man/man8` and `mkdir -p /usr/local/man/man5` if they aren't exist.